# createReadStream not firing close event

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to download a file and once downloaded i want to delete the file from server. I am trying to create a stream and pipe it with res and listening to close event to delete file from server.

```
res.set({
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=destination.pdf',
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        });
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        stream.pipe(res).once("close", function () {
            stream.destroy(); 

            fs.unlink(file, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.toString());
                } else {
                    console.warn(file + ' deleted');
                }
            });
        });
```

but close event is not firing.

Comment: Can you show us the code above this? The solution to your immediate question is to attach the "close" listener to the `stream` and not to `stream.pipe(res)` (which returns `res`). But it's odd to need to read from a disk once and then need to unlink the file from the file system, so please show what this route is actually trying to do.

Comment: @idbehold Above this, i am generating a pdf report using phantomjs and i want to delete that report from the server once user download it.

Comment: my point is that there probably isn't any need to store that generated PDF on your file system at all. Generate the PDF buffer/stream via phantomjs and then write/pipe it directly to the response instead of to your file system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,  as you suggested ,now i am generating a stream using phantomjs and piping it directly to the response.